# Redis and Internal Page Cache?

Tags: caching

I just set up Redis on a site that has been having some performance problems, and it seems to be running well so far. Does anybody know if it would be recommended to also run the Internal Page Cache and/or Internal Dynamic Page Cache module(s) in addition to Redis, or is this redundant? There isn't much documentation around yet regarding Redis and D8.

Comment: Redis is a cache storage backend. It makes caching faster, but doesn't change the way drupal caches data.

Comment: So then the answer would be that enabling those module is not redundant?

Comment: Only if speed is so much improved that you can do without one of those caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal modules decide *what* to cache (and for how long etc), Redis is just *where* the cached data is stored.

Having both/all enabled is not inherently redundant (though as 4k4 noted in the comments, there's a theoretical chance that one cache will improve speed so much that it renders the other redundant in terms of further speed improvements).

Enabling the lot will probably be common practice, and if not with Redis as the storage backend then Memcache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As said before Redis is just a "bin" where to store cache, it should be faster than the database bin (default Drupal cache bin).

- Dynamic Page Cache module should always be enabled or you get crappy performances.
- Internal Page Cache module could be disabled if you have already a cache server in front of your Drupal (for example, Varnish), this module cache whole pages for anonymous users only.

These two modules are enable by default on Drupal 8; it is safe to enable them.